# is it possible to use arrow function as variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, discord.js

I was wondering if an arrow function can serve as a variable instead of actually declaring a variable to make it much more cleaner.

```
bot.message = require('./json/message.json')
message.channel.send(confirmDiag(m => {
        m = bot.message['await'].welCH.complete
        Object.assign(m, {
          color: toggle === true ? '#ffffff':'#2c2f33',
          msg: m.msg.replace('{{stat}}', 'Disabled'),
          foot: 'You can also check info server'
        })
 }))
```

is it possible?

**Edit**: This question may have been confusing... *"I'm flying too close to the sun"*.
basically, this was my original code:

```
bot.message = require('./json/message.json')
let diagMsg = bot.message['await'].welCH.complete
  Object.assign(diagMsg, {
  color: toggle === true ? '#ffffff':'#2c2f33',
  msg: diagMsg.msg.replace('{{stat}}', 'Disabled'),
  foot: 'You can also check info server'
})
message.channel.send(confirmDiag(diagMsg)).then(del => del.delete(10000));
```

and I hoping if I could shorten it up by doing it inside *message.channel.send*.
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking here. Is *what* possible?

Comment: You mean `const confirmDiag = m => ...`yes

Comment: A function cannot be a variable, no. A function's *name* is sometimes a variable. If you've used a named function declaration, the function's name is added to the scope where the declaration occurs. If you've used a named function expression, the function's name is added to the scope within the function when it's called. Names associated with arrow functions are always explicitly declared variables or parameters.

Comment: just to clarify, confirmDiag()  is an embed function from another module.exports.

I was hoping if I can edit the parameter m inside confirmDiag() without declaring another variable

Comment: And of course, any function can be *assigned* to a variable. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @asehastly - *"I was hoping if I can edit the parameter m inside confirmDiag()"* Parameters are mutable, just like local variables within the function. So you can assign to it, yes (although doing so without using the value you received, as in the question, is not best practice). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: so, basically, I have to declare **m** outside _message.channel.send_ and then pass it to `confirmDiag()`. there's no other way....

Comment: "*I was hoping I could shorten it up*" - the code is quite concise already. Yes, it might be possible to shorten it up more, but that won't make it *cleaner*

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do like this, you can save the callback function that you pass into the new variable called `func` and then pass it to you function, it will look cleaner.

```js
bot.message = require('./json/message.json')
const func = m => {
        m = bot.message['await'].welCH.complete
        Object.assign(m, {
          color: toggle === true ? '#ffffff':'#2c2f33',
          msg: m.msg.replace('{{stat}}', 'Disabled'),
          foot: 'You can also check info server'
        }
}
message.channel.send(confirmDiag(func))
```

if that what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its posible.

```
var arrowFunc = m => {
  // arrow func code    
};

message.channel.send(confirmDiag(arrowFunc()))
```

Comment: Don't think you want those `()` on `arrowFunc` in `confirmDiag`. (But the question is so unclear who knows. But they aren't calling the function they pass in in the question.)